# Why node_modules is added when installing a local package to another local package?

Tags: typescript, package, yarnpkg

I'm a little bit confused when I search an answer to this issue.

I have created a typescript/nodejs package "firstmodule". After built, the DIST 
 folder contains only several  `.js` files into some subdirectories and  a `index.js` file

However, when adding this package as a dependency to another application  `yarn add c:\....\firstmodule` , the package is well installed in `c:\...\app\node_modules\firstmodule`, but **the node_modules of firstmodule is also installed** `c:\...\app\node_modules\firstmodule\node_modules\**`.
Why ? This incresases the size of the application a lot.

How to avoid this ? Looking at all the packages downloaded from NPM, none of them have their node_modules installed.

I guess there must be one option in a config file, but can not find which one.

Thks for guiding me.

**EDIT**

Here is a screenshot of the problem.
We can see that my local module "@C***\g****" has been well installed as a dependency.
However, its own node_modules also, whereas, for example, the @appolographql module is already installed in the pmain projet. It seems to me a weired issue

[image]

here is the package.json of the firsmodule :

```
{
    "name": "firstmodule",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "main": "./dist/index.js",
    "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
    "license": "MIT",
    "author": {
        "email": "****.com",
        "name": "***"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "Api"
    ],
    "scripts": {
        "build": "tsc",
        "start": "ts-node-dev --respawn src/index.ts",
        "prebuild": "yarn lint:fix && rm -rf dist",
        "lint": "./node_modules/.bin./eslint --ext ts ./src",
        "lint:fix": "yarn lint --fix"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
        "typescript": "^3.6.3"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=10"
    }
}
```

and this is the tsconfig

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "rootDirs": ["src"],
        "strict": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext.asynciterable"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "declaration": true,
        "composite": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "strictFunctionTypes": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true,
        "noUnusedParameters": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "resolveJsonModule": true
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules"],
    "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"],
    "typedocOptions": {
        "mode": "modules",
        "out": "docs"
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know if I understood your question correctly: When you install an npm package `A`, and this package has a dependency `B`, then of course `B` (transitive dependency) is also installed together with `A` itself, otherwise it would be missing in the runtime. The packages from npm package repository only include their own source files, but expect their dependencies to be installed nonetheless ( in contrast to web apps which are bundled together). And that is normal npm/yarn behavior as usual. Maybe you could explain your question  a bit more?

Comment: The point  is when installing B as a dependency of A, not only the DIST folder of B is installed in the A node_modules folder, but also all the node_modules folder of B. What I'm expecting is that only dist folder of B is installed, but not its NODE_MODULES folder, because at the end, the A packqge is huge

Comment: But that is also usual behavior. It is called dependency for a reason, you cannot leave it out unless its a `devDependency` for an external package. Normally npm installs all direct and transitive dependencies in the project's top `node_modules` folder. If there are divergent versions of the same package, the specific version gets install under its own `node_modules` folder of the package, where it is required.

Comment: have added screenshot to explain my problem